HTTP Request in Microsoft Power Automate not returning response body
When a Microsoft form is submitted, I am trying to pass the responder email to the GET user details JIRA API to get the user account id. The request seems successful as the response code is 200 but the response body is empty.

The same GET API run using Postman returns the body. I tried passing Content-Type:Application/Json and Accept:Application/Json

Any idea how can I get the body?
I tried passing Content-Type:Application/Json and Accept:Application/Json
Tried pass Authorization: encode64 (email+api token)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I figured out the solution for this. In the HTTP advanced body, you have an option to add authentication, just supply username and API token and Voila!!
